# iteration over 2d list in python and printing headings for each element

Tags: python

I am trying to work out how to iterate over a list and print out each item with a print statement describing what element is. my project is to create a user management system and print out something similar to the image I have attached.

[The output I am trying to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWEX.png)

[The output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6nQR.png)

My code:

```
records = 0
userFirst = ["John"]
userLast = ["Doe"]
autoUsername = ["Johndoe91"]
autoPassword = ["123456789"]
hiddenPassword = ["*****789"]
userRole = ["User"]
userDept = ["Administration"]
users = []  
confidentialUserDetails = []  

users.append(userFirst + userLast + userRole + userDept + autoUsername + autoPassword)
confidentialUserDetails.append(users)

for row in range(len(confidentialUserDetails)):
    records += 1
    print("-" * 25)
    print("Record: ", records)
    for col in range(len(confidentialUserDetails[row])):
        print(confidentialUserDetails[row][col])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html And please post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structures are unusual. I'm assuming that those lists are going to be provided to your code somehow and will, in practice, have multiple user details appended to them so that they are all the same length.

Anyhow, you can achieve the output you're looking for with some readable [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) like this:

```py
from functools import reduce

userFirst = ["John"]
userLast = ["Doe"]
autoUsername = ["Johndoe91"]
autoPassword = ["123456789"]
hiddenPassword = ["*****789"]
userRole = ["User"]
userDept = ["Administration"]

for row in range(len(userFirst)):
    s = (f"""\
Name          : {userFirst[row]} {userLast[row]}
Role          : {userRole[row]}
Department    : {userDept[row]}
Username      : {autoUsername[row]}
Password      : {hiddenPassword[row]}""")

    maxlen = reduce(lambda x,y: max(x, len(y)), s.split("\n"), 0)
    print(f"{s}\n{'-'*maxlen}\n")
```

Output:

```
Name          : John Doe
Role          : User
Department    : Administration
Username      : Johndoe91
Password      : *****789
------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I ended up using this and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Any, what does the below line of code actually do, I know the bottom print function prints a new line after each loop, from looking at the maxlen = reduce line, it seems like its used to properly format the f string, would this be a fair assessment?

maxlen = reduce(lambda x,y: max(x, len(y)), s.split("\n"), 0)
    print(f"{s}\n{'-'*maxlen}\n")

Comment: It finds the longest line length, in characters, of the lines that make up the string `s`. It does so by creating an iterable list of lines using `split` and then uses `reduce` to apply the `max` function to each line length, returning the overall greatest length.

Answer (score 1):

I created a dictionary called `user` instead of your list and after that I appended it to the second list and finally I printed the key and the value of the dictionary.

Also to get the full name I joined `userFirst` and `userLast` as string.

Code:

```
records = 0
userFirst = ["John"]
userLast = ["Doe"]
autoUsername = ["Johndoe91"]
autoPassword = ["123456789"]
hiddenPassword = ["*****789"]
userRole = ["User"]
userDept = ["Administration"]

confidentialUserDetails = []  # 2d list for asterisked passwords

users={'Name' : [' '.join(userFirst + userLast)] ,'Role' : userRole , 'Departement' : userDept ,'Username' : autoUsername ,'Password' : hiddenPassword }
confidentialUserDetails.append(users)

for user in confidentialUserDetails:
    records += 1
    print("-" * 25)
    print("Record: ", records)
    for ele,v in user.items():
        print(ele,':',v[0])
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
Record:  1
Name : John Doe
Role : User
Departement : Administration
Username : Johndoe91
Password : *****789
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary or f strings like the two other answers suggested is probably the best. But if you just want to use your current code to print your desired output, you can simply grab each item by its index number in your print statement.

Change the line:

```
print(confidentialUserDetails[row][col])
```

To something like this:

```
print("Name          : ", confidentialUserDetails[row][col][0], confidentialUserDetails[row][col][1])
print("Role:         : ", confidentialUserDetails[row][col][2])
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
Record:  1
Name          :  John Doe
Role:         :  User
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used this to complete my application!

Comment: @JDF91 This was my only best answer, and now I lost it! lol

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to re alter my program! and ended up using a different one, it was a good answer tho :)

Comment: @JDF91 haha No problem, as long as you got your answer. Thanks for the upvote